# How to make a search view between 2 dates?

Tags: xml, odoo-8, searchview, odoo, odoo-10

I got a model (Activity) with a Field Date ("date") on it. And I want to implement on my module a search view than finds the activities between 2 dates.

Anyone knows how? I made a search view by description but dont know how to implement this:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="activity_search_view">
    <field name="name">activity.search</field>
    <field name="model">proyectosge.activity</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search>
            <field name="description"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Static and relative dates

If the dates are always the same you can create a filter like this

```xml
<filter string="This Year" 
        name="thisyear"
        domain="['|', ('date', '=', False), '&amp;',('date','&lt;=', time.strftime('%%Y-12-31')),('date','&gt;=',time.strftime('%%Y-01-01'))]" 
        help="Journal invoices with period in current year" />
```

So, take a look at the domain, more examples (this year, this month, today, static dates):

```py
domain="[('date','&lt;=', time.strftime('%%Y-12-31')),('date','&gt;=',time.strftime('%%Y-01-01'))]"
domain="[('date','&lt;=', time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),('date','&gt;=',time.strftime('%Y-%m-01'))]"
domain="[('date','&lt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today(), datetime.time(23,59,59))), ('date','&gt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today(), datetime.time(0,0,0)))]"
domain="[('date','&lt;=', time.strftime('2020-12-31')),('date','&gt;=',time.strftime('2000-01-01'))]"
```

### Dynamic dates

If they are not static you must add both conditions with the advanced search. You can add the filter to favourites as well

[image]

> **Note:** Keep in mind that you have to press the **"Apply"** to add each condition in the advanced search to use an **"and"** operator. Don´t press the button **"Add a condition"** because you are going to use an **"or"** operator